# How to write a SQL query to fetch the data from both tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaigns")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CampaignResultSet", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Campaign.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "campaign_sno", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "campaign_id", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "campaign_title", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "campaign_label", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "campaign_description", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "campaign_type", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "email_subject", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "from_name", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "from_email", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "to_name_type", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "email_type", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "email_status", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "api_key", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "list_id", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "created_by", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "created_date", type = Date.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "updated_by", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "updated_date", type = Date.class) }) }, entities = {
                        @EntityResult(entityClass = Template.class, fields = {
                                @FieldResult(name = "templateSno", column = "template_sno"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "baseTemplateId", column = "base_template_id"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "templateName", column = "template_name"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "bodyHeader", column = "body_header"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "bodySubject", column = "body_subject"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "bodyContent", column = "body_content"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "bodyFooter", column = "body_footer"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "sourceCode", column = "source_code"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "modifiedCode", column = "modified_code"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "extractedCode", column = "extracted_code"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "createdBy", column = "created_by"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "createdDate", column = "created_date"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "updatedBy", column = "updated_by"),
                                @FieldResult(name = "updatedDate", column = "updated_date") }) })
```

My Query is **select * from campaigns**.
In campaigns table, I have a reference column name as **template_id** and it will refer the **template_sno** column in templates table. While retrieving campaigns, I need the template data also. So, how the way to write a query to fetch the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query would help you in displaying all the fields from both the tables only if the data is related.

SELECT * 
FROM campaigns c
JOIN templates t ON c.template_id=t.template_id;

Comment: Awesome... But, I've changed the result set mapping to @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CampaignResultSet", entities = { @EntityResult(entityClass = Campaign.class) })